# How to set Encoding

Tags: encoding

I wrote a small file joining program with some functionality, all works fine, but I have to set encoding of output file to utf8 without bom. I tried to add on the beginning of program this line "$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'" but result was that I've got a utf8 with bom. I've tried to use -Encoding utf8NoBOM but not work(I've got error).I Work on PS Version 5.What I should do to get UTF8 without bom?

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't need a BOM.

Comment: @Raedwald I know but, and i want to got this. If i run my script and after that check the outfile encoding(in notepad) i see UTF-8 with bom, and i want to get utf-8 without bom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PowerShell version 7.X, you can simply add parameter `-Encoding utf8NoBOM` to `Add-Content`.

If your version is below 7.X, you could use this:

```
# The StreamWriter class by default uses Utf8 without BOM encoding

# get a StreamWriter to a new or existing file to append text to
$streamWriter = [System.IO.File]::AppendText('D:\Test\Blah.txt')

# or if you want to overwrite an existing file, use this 
# $streamWriter = [System.IO.File]::CreateText('D:\Test\Blah.txt')

# or this:
# $streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new('D:\Test\Blah.txt', $true)  # $true for Append
```

Next write your content using this instead of `Add-Content`

```
$streamWriter.WriteLine("blah something that needs UTF8: €")
```

And when all writing is done, close the file and release the StreamWriter object

```
$streamWriter.Dispose()
```